# Excel VBA FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code:

```
Dim Output As String
Output = "=SUM(C4:C" & ActiveCell.Row - 2 & ")"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Output
```

I am at C56
Output shows this as it's value `"=Sum(C4:C54)"`
But the Cell ends up with `=SUM($D:$BB)`

I am stumped.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: .Formula rather than .FormulaR1C1 should fix it

Comment: ^^ `C4` in R1C1 notation means "column 4" (i.e. `$D` in A1 notation).  Similarly `C54` means "column 54" which is column `$BB` in A1 notation.